# Beginner Python Functions Functions and Loops

Tags: python, function

My code is as follows:

```
import random

def CalcMulti(TT,TB):
    ResultMutli = (TT * TB)
    Answer1 = (input("What is the result of",TT,"*",TB,"?"))
    if (ResultMulti == Answer1):
        print("That is correct, the answer is",ResultMulti)
    else: 
        print("That's not correct, sorry! The answer was",ResultMulti)

def CalcDivi(TT,TB):
    ResultDivi = (TT / TB)
    Answer2 = int(input("What is the result of ",TT,"/",TB,"?"))
    if (ResultDivi == Answer2):
        print("That is correct, the answer is",ResultDivi)
    else: 
        print("That's not correct, sorry! The answer was",ResultDivi)

print("Thank you for using my program! Let's begin at the menu.")
print("")
ProgramLoop = 1
while (ProgramLoop == 1):
    Num1 = random.randint(1,99)
    Num2 = random.randint(1,99)
    print("Your two numbers are",Num1,"and",Num2,". What should we do with     these?")
print("")
print("1. Multiplication")
print("")
print("2. Division")
print("")
print("3. Exit Program")
print("")
MenuDecision =  input("Enter M for Multiplication, D for Division, or E to Exit Menu!")
ExitLoop = 1
if (MenuDecision == "E") or (MenuDecision == "e"):
    ProgramLoop = 0
    print("Thank you for using my program! Bye!")
    ExitLoop = 0
elif (MenuDecision == "D") or (MenuDecision == "d"):
    CalcDivi(Num1,Num2)
elif (MenuDecision =="M") or (MenuDecision == "m"):
    CalcMulti(Num1,Num2)
else:
    print("Not a valid entry, sorry! Restarting...")
    ExitLoop = 0
    ProgramLoop = 1
while (ExitLoop == 1):
    ProgramExit = input("Would you like to continue using the program? (yes/no)")
    if (ProgramExit=="yes") or (ProgramExit=="YES") or (ProgramExit=="Yes"):
        print("Back to the menu we go!")
        ProgramLoop = 1
        ExitLoop = 0
    elif (ProgramExit=="no") or (ProgramExit=="NO") or (ProgramExit=="No"):
        print("Thank you for using my program! Bye!")
        ProgramLoop = 0
        ExitLoop = 0
    else:
        print("Not a valid entry, yes or no please!")
        ExitLoop = 1
```

Whenever I run the program and input "M" or "D" I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\xxxxxxxxx Assignment 4.py",     line 44, in <module>
    CalcMulti(Num1,Num2)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\xxxxxxxx Assignment 4.py",     line 7, in CalcMulti
    Answer1 = (input("What is the result of",TT,"*",TB,"?"))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
```

Comment: Specifically, the problem is that when I call my functions within my MenuDecision point of code, the function fails to call and gives the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` expects a single string as its input. Currently, you are passing it 5 strings. You should do something like the following:

```
def CalcMulti(TT,TB):
    ResultMutli = (TT * TB)
    string = "What is the result of {}*{}?".format(TT,TB)
    Answer1 = input(string)
    if (ResultMulti == Answer1):
        print("That is correct, the answer is",ResultMulti)
    else: 
        print("That's not correct, sorry! The answer was",ResultMulti)
```

Answer (score 1):

[input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function takes only one argument. Correct way is something like this:

```
input("What is the result of %s * %s?" % (TT, TB))
```